# XSL loop through XML element's attributes and then replace first element with the concatenated attributes

Tags: xml, xslt, foreach, concatenation

here is my file for example

```
<offer>
<products>
  <product>
    <images>
        <large>
          <image priority="1" url="data/gfx/pictures/large/9/7/70679_1.jpg" hash="74c757e1dfc9277d6f6ba49c0ca*****" changed="2021-06-18 15:57:02" width="1000" height="1000"/>
          <image priority="2" url="data/gfx/pictures/large/9/7/70679_2.jpg" hash="74c757e1dfc9277d6f6ba49c0ca*****" changed="2021-06-18 15:57:02" width="1000" height="1000"/>
          <image priority="3" url="data/gfx/pictures/large/9/7/70679_3.jpg" hash="74c757e1dfc9277d6f6ba49c0ca*****" changed="2021-06-18 15:57:02" width="1000" height="1000"/>
        </large>
    </images>
  </product>
</products>
</offer>
```

I want to combine all image URL attributes with /// (can be any number of image elements)
In the below example that has 3 image element, for example, the result that I need is:

```
<offer>
<products>
  <product>
    <images>
        <large>

          <image priority="1" url="data/gfx/pictures/large/9/7/70679_1.jpg///data/gfx/pictures/large/9/7/70679_2.jpg///data/gfx/pictures/large/9/7/70679_3.jpg" hash="74c757e1dfc9277d6f6ba49c0ca*****" changed="2021-06-18 15:57:02" width="1000" height="1000"/>
          
        </large>
    </images>
  </product>
</products>
</offer>
```

I tried this but failed

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
    version="2.0">

<xsl:template match="/offer/products/product/images/large/image">
        <xsl:for-each select="image[*]/@url">
            <xsl:value-of select="concat(../../../images/large/image/@path,'///')"/>                    
        </xsl:for-each>
        
 </xsl:template>
 </xsl:stylesheet>
```

how is this possible? thank you in advance for your help

Comment: While asking a question you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) Input XML.
(2) Your logic, and XSLT that tried to implement it.
(3) Desired output.
(4) XSLT processor and its compliance with the XSLT standards: 1.0, 2.0, or 3.0.

Comment: @YitzhakKhabinsky thank you for your advice, i am totally new to coding especially XPATH and XLS. I am using oxygenxml that has Saxon PE 9.9.1.7 and XPATH 2.0. 
because the above code I am little sure that need "for" or "foreach" loop, I tried to find any clue online but I couldn't. The ways I tried to implement the above result all failed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try the following XSLT.

The Saxon PE 9.9.1.7 is compliant with XSLT 3.0

The `string-join()` function does all the magic.

**XSLT**

```
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="3.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" expand-text="yes">
   <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
   <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

   <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>

   <xsl:template match="large">
      <xsl:copy>
         <image priority="1"
                           url="{string-join((image/@url), '///')}"
                           hash="{image[1]/@hash}"
                           changed="{image[1]/@changed}" width="{image[1]/@width}"
                           height="{image[1]/@height}"/>
      </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: @SioulisNick, I made one XSLT 3.0 pertaining modification to make it less verbose. Please give it a shot.

Comment: yeah worked way faster than the previous and the result is the desired one! I have to study more that XSLT 3.0 is so powerful

Answer (score 2):

Your example is ambiguous. See if this can work for you:

**XSLT 2.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="large">
    <xsl:copy>
        <image>
            <xsl:copy-of select="image[1]/@*"/>
            <xsl:attribute name="url" select="image/@url" separator="//"/>
        </image>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: worked as well! really thank you! just had to revise seperator to /// from //